# How to design a system that scrapes Elasticsearch and hits millions of requests to a service

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture, scalability, software-design, system-design

We need to design a system that filters(based on user-defined criteria) requests stored in Elasticsearch, modify these requests and call a gRPC service. The corresponding responses then should be stored in a Hadoop database table.

The main complexity of designing the aforementioned system is the scalability. The requirement is to filter and execute the requests in millions.

Can someone please help me with a high level design of such a system that can perform these tasks in a reasonable time?

Comment: How much modifications do you need to perform? Can you do it in the same service that call the Elasticsearch filter? Is the gRPC server scalable?

Comment: The modifications are not much. Just little configuration change in every request. We can do it in the same service that calls the ES. The gRPC server is scalable.